# Unable to choose compress program

Tags: tar, compression

I can't choose the compress program while using tar v1.26.

While this works

```
tar -c -I 'xz' -f foo.tar.xz *
```

This won't work:

```
tar -c -I 'xz -T0' -f foo.tar.xz *

tar (child): xz -T0: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Works with GNU `tar` 1.34, and the manual explicitly says `The argument can contain command line options.` about the `-I` option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your version of `tar` doesn’t support specifying options with `-I`; the `-I` argument must be the compressor’s executable name only. This was changed [in version 1.27](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/plain/NEWS?id=release_1_27).

In your case, you can run `xz` separately, as explained [by Romeo Ninov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/682687/86440), or you can specify the options using `XZ_OPT`:

```
XZ_OPT=-T0 tar -c -I xz -f foo.tar.xz *
```

Comment: I also found the solution which you are providing, works well with the environment variable. What I am still wondering: Is your solution faster then compared to the solution of Romeo Ninov? The data I am compressing is rather big...

Comment: @EverythingRightPlace both approaches will have the same performance. As Marcus says, the main factor is going to be the compressor’s speed (but the comment about running the compressor on every file is incorrect).

Comment: @EverythingRightPlace Should be no difference. `tar` is just doing Roman Ninov's thing internally

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure you can provide arguments to `xz` when run "in" `tar`. What you can do is to pipe the `tar` output to `xz`:

```
tar -cf - *|xz -T0 foo.tar.xz
```

or (not sure how `xz` will handle the filename)

```
tar -cf - *|xz -T0 --stdout >foo.tar.xz
```

Also this approach have benefit of parallel execution

Comment: Current GNU tar manpage says you *can* provide arguments. So, hm.

Comment: `tar -I` also benefits from parallel execution, the compression program is forked and the archive is fed to it as it’s generated. Your first variant won’t work, `xz` will try to compress `foo.tar.xz`.

Comment: @StephenKitt, had no idea about `-I` option :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, this may be true about Linux, but not sure about Unices

Comment: Marcus’ comment is true about GNU `tar` version 1.27 or later, on all platforms. Of course which `tar` is the default on various platforms varies ;-).